# get_post_gallery full size image

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get all the gallery images from a single post. Here in `get_post_gallery()` the variable `$image` returns the thumbnail URL. Can any one help me with retrieving full size image URL from the post.

```
    $gallery = get_post_gallery(get_the_ID(), false )

    foreach( $gallery['src'] as $image ) {

       $image_list . = '<li>' . $image . '</li>';

    }
```

Comment: `var_dump($gallery)` will probably show you what you need.

Comment: solved it $fullsizeimage= str_replace("-150x150", "", $image) solved my problem . But this is not the proper wordpress solution.

Answer (score 5):

This work for me:

```
$gallery = get_post_gallery( $post, false );
$ids = explode( ",", $gallery['ids'] );

foreach( $ids as $id ) {

   $link   = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );

   $image_list . = '<li>' . $link . '</li>';

}
```

Thanks to **Matt** for this code, see the [original post](http://pippinsplugins.com/retrieving-image-urls-of-galleries/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
  <?php wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $size, $icon, $attr ); ?>
```

where you give the attachment id of the gallery image in $attachment_id and 
$size = (thumbnail, medium, large or full) 
here basically you choose full as you want to display the full size image.
Let me know if this helped you . :)